# using Highcharters in R with Shiny, control highstock chart height failed

Tags: r, highcharts, shiny, r-highcharter

I called highchart with height parameter to make a taller chart successfully in RStudio:

```
chart <- highchart(type = "stock", height=800, ...)
```

When in Shiny, the chart shown up but ignore the height parameter. Is there any way to fix it ?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using shiny you can set the dimension in the `highchartOutput()` function:

```
# ui.R
...
highchartOutput("my_hc_id", width = 450, height = 300)
...
```

Other way using the `hc_size` function compared with the @pork-chop answer:

```
library(quantmod)
library(highcharter)
x <- getSymbols("GOOG", auto.assign = FALSE)

b <- hchart(x)
b <- hc_size(b, width = 450, height = 300)
b
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
library(quantmod)
library(highcharter)
x <- getSymbols("GOOG", auto.assign = FALSE)

a <- hchart(x)
a$width <- 450
a$height <- 300
a
```

[image]